# WinJS forward custom object to print function

Tags: javascript, printing, win-universal-app, winjs

I use WinJS in my application and try to print some content. Made my printer class according to this tutorial https://dzone.com/articles/windows-8-print-contract-%E2%80%93.

```
function registerForPrintContract(participiantData) {
    var printManager = Windows.Graphics.Printing.PrintManager.getForCurrentView();
    printManager.addEventListener("printtaskrequested", onPrintTaskRequested, false);
}

function onPrintTaskRequested(printEvent) {
    var printTask = printEvent.request.createPrintTask("Print Example", function (args) {
        printCurrentPage(args);

        printTask.oncompleted = onPrintTaskCompleted;
    });
}

function printCurrentPage(args) {
    var docHtml = document.createDocumentFragment();
    docHtml.appendChild(createDocumentContent());
    args.setSource(MSApp.getHtmlPrintDocumentSource(docHtml));   
}

function createDocumentContent() {
    var container = document.createElement("div");
    container.innerHTML = "<h2>" + firstname + " " + lastname + "</h2>" +
                          "<h4>" + emailaddress1 + "<h4>";
    return container;
}

function showPrintUI() {
    Windows.Graphics.Printing.PrintManager.showPrintUIAsync();
}
```

My problem is that I do not know how to forward some object data to createDocumentContent() function. In this example I put firstname, lastname and email. Those data I cannot get from html page I need to send them on print button click.

All examples I saw are about printing current page or making new content from data which we can get from HTML page by querying DOM, no example where I can send custom object.
What is the best way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

> My problem is that I do not know how to forward some object data to createDocumentContent() function. In this example I put firstname, lastname and email. Those data I cannot get from html page I need to send them on print button click.

Do you mean you want to put the html output of `"<h2>"+firstname + " " +lastname+"</h2>"+"<h4>" + emailaddress1 + "<h4>"` to your print page?

The behavior of innerHTML has changed in Windows Store App Development.
see [HTML and DOM API changes list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700404.aspx) innerHTML section:

> Content is filtered as through it was processed by the toStaticHTML method

---

But WinJS offers a method that you can utilize to inject HTML.

Here is the link to documentation of this method: [WinJS.Utilities.insertAdjacentHTML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229833.aspx)

Here is a code snippet that shows a simple use this method:

```
function createDocumentContent() {
    var obj = {
        firstname: "winffee",
        lastname: "xia",
        emailaddress1:"test@126.com"
    }
    var htmlString = "<h2>" + obj.firstname + " " + obj.lastname + "</h2>" +
                      "<h4>" + obj.emailaddress1 + "<h4>";
    var container = document.createElement("div");
    WinJS.Utilities.insertAdjacentHTML(container, "beforeend", htmlString);
    return container;
}
```